# Return values in recursive function in java

Tags: java, recursion

here is a simple function that searches for a file in a given folder and its subfolders i am able to find the file but somehow the return value is a null and can someone also explain what happens in the stack when we use recursive functions if you can relate it to my scenario it would be great...

```
File getFileInFolder(File folder, String fileName) {

    //System.out.println(" PathTo : "+folder.getAbsolutePath());
    File [] files = folder.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                return getFileInFolder(files[i],fileName);
            } else {
                //System.out.println(" file : "+files[i].getName());
                if (files[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
                System.out.println(" Found file : "+files[i].getName());
                    return files[i];
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved it using a bool variable filefound and i break all the loops in the stack, don"t know if it is the best way to do it but it works for me

```
boolean filefound = false;
File getFileInFolder(File folder, String fileName) {
    filefound = false;
    //System.out.println(" PathTo : "+folder.getAbsolutePath());
    File [] files = folder.listFiles();
    File file = null;
    if (files != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                file = getFileInFolder(files[i],fileName);
                if(filefound) {
                    file= files[i];
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                //System.out.println(" file : "+files[i].getName());
                if (files[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    System.out.println(" Found file : "+files[i].getName());
                    file= files[i];
                    filefound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you're looking for a.txt in the following folder:

```
root
    sub1
        b.txt
    sub2
        a.txt
```

What your algorithm does is

1. List the files in root. That returns sub1 and sub2.
2. Iterate through the files. If the file is a directory, return the result of the method on this directory

So, the algorithm will search only in sub1, and that will return null.

You need to continue searching in other directories if the file wasn't found in the first one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        File resultForSubDirectory = getFileInFolder(files[i], fileName);
        if (resultForSubDirectory != null) {
            return resultForSubDirectory;
        } // else: continue looping
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```